# This estimator does not support Dask dataframes

Tags: python, dask

I am trying to fit a model using Dask framework, and the estimator used in example says it does not accept Dask dataframe. Can someone help me please ?

```
    from dask_ml.model_selection import IncrementalSearchCV
    from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier

    ddx,ddy = dd.from_pandas(X,chunksize=100000), 
    dd.from_pandas(y,chunksize=100000)
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(ddx, ddy)
    model = SGDClassifier(loss='log')
    params = { 'alpha': np.logspace(-2, 1, num=1000) }
    search = IncrementalSearchCV(model, params,
                         n_initial_parameters=10, random_state=0)
    search.fit(X_train, y_train, classes=classes)
    y_pred = search.predict_proba(X_test)
```

The error log is : TypeError: This estimator does not support dask dataframes.

It appears on the search fit line. When I replace by **partial_fit** it works but then the same error happens on the **predict_proba** line.

Comment: Please provide more context. More specifically - how do you import the `SGDClassifier` and `IncrementalSearchCV`? Also, is this the row where the error occurs - `search.fit(X_train, y_train, classes=classes)`?

Comment: Also, everything works fine when i use **Incremental** instead of **IncrementalSearchCV** but the issue is : I need to optimize the hyperparameters.

Comment: Is there a chance `dask_ml` also provides an `SGDClassifier`? Maybe you should use the "dask version" if there is one, of course.

Comment: Also, if you update your question with what you told me in the comments (here), it would be better for others who read it and would be able to help you more :)

Comment: Dask uses these imports on its quick-run examples so it should work with these imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IncrementalSearchCV currently requires Dask Arrays, perhaps you can [convert your data](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.to_dask_array).

I opened https://github.com/dask/dask-ml/issues/628 to suport dataframes. Would welcome help if you're interested in working on it.

Comment: Hello, my X_train data has several columns. What you are saying is that I can't use IncrementalSearchCV to optimize the model for now ? How can I help on the Github issue ?